# aws sync failing to download objects with spaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to sync a bucket from s3 to my local storage and it's only throwing errors or objects that have spaces. Is there a way to run this command so that it either ignores the spaces or replaces them with `%20` to better handle them?

**Command**

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket . --endpoint-url <ENDPOINT> --no-verify-ssl --profile test
```

**Error**

```
download: s3://bucket/test-124.htm to local\test-124.htm
Completed 20.5 MiB/149.3 MiB (6.9 MiB/s) with 221 file(s) remaining
download: s3://bucket/test-123.htm to local\test-123.htm
Completed 21.5 MiB/149.3 MiB (7.2 MiB/s) with 220 file(s) remaining
download failed: s3://bucket/test+285.json to local\test+285.json An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
download failed: s3://bucket/test+300.json to local\test+300.json An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
download failed: s3://bucket/test+855.json to local\test+855.json An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
download failed: s3://bucket/test+744.json to local\test+744.json An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Comment: Are you talking to a S3 server, or some other service?  AWS documents it's encoding scheme to encode spaces as `%20` and never `+`, and thus the AWS CLI expects that.  If you're using some other service that doesn't adhere to those rules, the CLI won't operate properly.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you open a bug with the vendor of the appliance, or find a community to report the issue.  It's using the wrong URL encoding when listing objects.  As for working around it:  I know of no way to convince the AWS cli to use a different decoding when parsing responses, so you'll need to write a custom sync tool to deal with the oddity.